# Hypothesis testing of standard deviation for two samples with different mean and size

Tags: r, statistics

In a random sample of size 500, the mean is found to be 20. In another independent sample of size 400, the mean is 15. Could the samples have been drawn from the same population with standard deviation 4.

Comment: Very simple answer. Yes. Everything is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reasonably large sample size for central limit theorem to work.

Let the Null hypothesis be that the standard error is 4, in other words, the variance is 16. Then we have approximately variance `16 / 500` for the first sample mean, and `16 / 400` for the second sample mean. Thus the difference in two sets of observed sample mean has variance `16 / 500 + 16 / 400`, which is about `0.2683` in standard error.

Note that under Null hypothesis, the mean of the difference should be 0 (because two sets come from the same population). Thus:

```
difference of sample mean ~ N(0, 0.2683 ^ 2)
```

However, you have an observed difference `20 - 5`. You can get p-value:

```
2 * pnorm(5, 0, 0.2683, lower = FALSE)
# 1.645e-77
```

which rejects the Null hypothesis.